# Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread while using @Async

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

Getting below error.
 Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread while using @Async

```
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.domainMetadata': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a s...","level":"ERROR","logger":"org.springframework.aop.interceptor.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler","thread":"SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-3","throwable_class":"FatalBeanException","throwable_root_cause_class":"java.lang.IllegalStateException"}

@Async 
public String sample(Event obj){ 
eventProcess.processObject(obj); 
}
```

While executing processObject object i am getting the above exception. But the flow is not getting terminated. processObject method is present in another dependency not in the same application

Comment: Be more specific about what you are doing and what are you trying to achieve. Add code snippets and stack trace. BTW Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: We are trying to make a asynchronous call. When we are trying to access the method in other dependencies getting this exception.

Comment: Hi Hari, please post the code associated with your error, so that we can better understand what you're needs are and thus provide more comprehensive and tailored answers.

Comment: @ManikantaP                                                                                                                     I have updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, an @Async thread cannot be bound to or use request scope as there is no request scope in the asynchronous execution.

Comment: How to solve this issue? Can you please help me on this

Comment: You have to use something else than request scope or don't use the Beans that are request-scoped in the async context.

Comment: We are trying to make a asynchronous call. When we are trying to access the method in other dependencies getting this exception

Comment: @NathanHughes I am able to proceed with the flow.. But, while executing the method in other dependencies getting this exception in console.   Flow is not getting terminated..